# For which boundaries of the Mandelbrot set are known to be parameterized by radical algebraic functions?

Tags: group-theory, dynamical-systems, complex-dynamics

For example, the boundary of period 1 can be parametrized by $X(1-X)$ for $$X=\frac{e^{\imath t}}{2},$$ period 2 can be parameterized by $X/2-1$, and period 3 boundaries are expressible as the solution of a cubic. Are there any other period boundaries that can be parameterized in radicals? They are all algebraic functions of $X$ though, that I am certain of!

Comment: It's known that the period 4 components lead to polynomials with Galois group $S_6$, so I guess we can't express the boundaries in terms of radicals of $e^{it}$. This is discussed in the last section of [A Parameterization of the Period 3 Hyperbolic Components of the Mandelbrot Set](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2161901). I see no reason to think we can go higher than 3.